# Ipad number field code

Tags: java, php, ipad

Im looking for a way to convert my normal html text field into a Numpad field for the Ipad.
So when users click to enter numbers in the field on Ipad, it will automaticly show the Numpad on the Ipad, and the user dont have to select the numpad from the characterpad.

Best regards.

Comment: What do you mean by html text field?

Answer (score 0):

Following enum is defined for keyboard type -

```
typedef enum {
    UIKeyboardTypeDefault,                // Default type for the current input method.
    UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable,           // Displays a keyboard which can enter ASCII characters, non-ASCII keyboards remain active
    UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation,  // Numbers and assorted punctuation.
    UIKeyboardTypeURL,                    // A type optimized for URL entry (shows . / .com prominently).
    UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad,              // A number pad (0-9). Suitable for PIN entry.
    UIKeyboardTypePhonePad,               // A phone pad (1-9, *, 0, #, with letters under the numbers).
    UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad,           // A type optimized for entering a person's name or phone number.
    UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress,           // A type optimized for multiple email address entry (shows space @ . prominently).
    #if __IPHONE_4_1 <= __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
    UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad,             // A number pad with a decimal point.
    #endif
    #if __IPHONE_5_0 <= __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED
    UIKeyboardTypeTwitter,                // A type optimized for twitter text entry (easy access to @ #)
    #endif

    UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet = UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable, // Deprecated

} UIKeyboardType;
```

You can choose appropriate keyboard type as per your need.
Like with text field -

```
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
```

Comment: Hi cbuckley, how would you insert that into a php document? It just gives me a error.